# Store application assets Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase

Firebase has 3 type of storage but they are geared towards user-generated data and cross-device syncing.

How to use firebase in order to store multiple static graphical assets(e.g. image assets), without having to manually copy and paste links into the app's code?

Thanks

Comment: if the images are static (they dont change) store them in the apps resources... if you have a ton of images, store them on a server and then load the .jpg into a imageview.  you can use picasso. if the images are dynamic (they change, user uploaded, etc etc) you can use firebase... do a google search for saving images in firebase

Comment: I have images that are both static, and dynamic, also I know the workings of image saving but it would be highly efficient if firebase gave all the links in a specific folder, for example.  I'm saving them in firebase storage and using glide to load them, but as the number of images grow, this solution is not practical...

Comment: cross that bridge when you get there.... if you are worried about how images are sent from a server to the app, look into how instagram does it. i think you will be VERY surprised how they handle those responses. they get the images BEFORE you even see it. and they SAVE the image as you are editing it. quite neat stuff actually.

Answer (score 0):

You can make one Upload activity which store URL of your graphical assets to database automatically in these case you have to upload graphical assets from device. For that uploading code is following.

```
        storageReference2nd.putFile(FilePathUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Uploaded Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
                        ImageUploadInfo imageUploadInfo = new ImageUploadInfo(taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                        String ImageUploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                        // Adding image upload id s child element into databaseReference.
                        databaseReference.child(ImageUploadId).setValue(imageUploadInfo);
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

                        // Showing exception erro message.
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        // Setting progressDialog Title.


                    }
                });
```